# Mysql UPDATE multi rows on table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, multirow

I have a `table1` that has column `id_month` with value=`1` and `months` with value = `6` and going to update it from 6 to 12. I need this changes effect on `table2` to select all rows that has `id_months` with value= `1` and change the `months` to `12` and make a calculation `date_start`+ the new value of `months` and update `date_end` with the new date.

table1 like that

```
id_month | months
1        | 6
2        | 12
```

table2 like that

```
id | id_month | months | date_start  | date_end
1  | 1        | 6      | 2016-01-01  | 2016-07-01
2  | 1        | 6      | 2016-03-01  | 2016-09-01
3  | 1        | 6      | 2016-06-01  | 2016-12-01
4  | 1        | 6      | 2016-08-01  | 2017-02-01
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are your date fields actually of CHAR|VARCHAR type?

Comment: date type! 2016-01-01

Comment: whew! lol ....answer incoming.

Comment: data type can be `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` or `DATE` or `DATETIME` ... you show Table1 and Table2 but I dont see what output you want

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you can use fields in date math...

```
UPDATE table1 SET months = 12 where id_month = 1;
UPDATE table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id_month = t2.id_month
SET t2.months = t1.months, t2.date_end = t2.date_start + INTERVAL t1.months MONTH
WHERE t1.id_month = 1;
```

If not, this will accomplish it all in one query anyway....

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id_month = t2.id_month
SET t1.months = 12
  , t2.months = 12
  , t2.date_end = t2.date_start + INTERVAL 12 MONTH
WHERE t1.id_month = 1;
```

Sidenote: The need for this is why I try to avoid storing redundant data unless not doing so is costly from a performance perspective; the need to keep derived data in agreement.